# Vertical scrollbar of JQueryMobile Autocomplete is not working on Android

Tags: android, jquery

I am using jQuery Autocomplete on my jQUeryMobile application. It works perfect. Now I am trying to show vertical scrollbar to scroll through the list of looked up items. The scrollbar shows up on desktop browsers, but not on Android devices. my css looks like this:

.ui-autocomplete 
    {
        max-height: 100px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

Can someone help, thanks!

Comment: Which browser are you using in android device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Resolved by using jscrollpane. see below code:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var availableTags = [{
                real_value: 1,
                label: "c++"
            },
                {
                    real_value: 1,
                    label: "ActionScript"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 2,
                    label: "AppleScript"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 3,
                    label: "Asp"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 4,
                    label: "BASIC"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 5,
                    label: "C"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 6,
                    label: "C++"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 7,
                    label: "Clojure"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 8,
                    label: "COBOL"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 9,
                    label: "ColdFusion"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 10,
                    label: "Erlang"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 11,
                    label: "Fortran"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 12,
                    label: "Groovy"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 13,
                    label: "Haskell"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 14,
                    label: "Java"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 15,
                    label: "JavaScript"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 16,
                    label: "Lisp"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 17,
                    label: "Perl"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 18,
                    label: "PHP"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 19,
                    label: "Python"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 20,
                    label: "Ruby"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 21,
                    label: "Scala"
                },
                {
                    real_value: 22,
                    label: "Scheme"
                }
            ];

            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags,
                open: function(event, ui) {
                    $('.ui-autocomplete')
                        .addClass('scroll-pane')
                        .jScrollPane();

                    $('.jScrollPaneContainer').css({
                        'position': 'absolute',
                        'top': ($(this).offset().top +
                   $(this).height() + 5) + 'px',
                        'left': $(this).offset().left + 'px'
                    });
                },
                close: function(event, ui) {
                    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPaneRemove();
                },
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    alert(ui.item.label);
                    alert(ui.item.real_value);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        .ui-autocomplete
        {
            max-height: 100px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="tags" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting the overflow property to auto..

```
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: no this is not working.... when i try to scroll in looked up list then it use page scroll instead of looked up list scroll in mobile.